# What is the best way to get around these Hibernate exepctions when swithching from MySql to an in memory database for testing?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working on a Spring Boot application that uses MySql as it's data source. There is an entity in the application that has a field with the defintion:

```
@Column(name = "Vendor", columnDefinition="TEXT")
private String vendor;
```

The definition of the column in the database is `varchar(255)` which is why I suspect the entity has been given the `columnDefintion` of `'TEXT'`, since without it I get the exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in database.example for column Vendor. Found: text, expected: varchar(255)
```

This is fine when I'm running the application and it talks to the MySql database. The problems come when I want to run some tests that talk to an in memory database (hsqldb in this case) configured as below:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource meshlium()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:meshlium");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Declare the JPA entity manager factory.
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryOffice = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryOffice.setDataSource(meshlium());

        // Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class
        entityManagerFactoryOffice
                .setPackagesToScan("com.mottmac.meshlium.scan");

        // Vendor adapter
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactoryOffice.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        // Hibernate properties
        Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
                true);
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        additionalProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        entityManagerFactoryOffice.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryOffice;
    }
```

When I run my tests and hibernate tries to create the database I get exceptions in the log file:

```
2016-05-05 15:44:31.020(GMT)[main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: create table bluetoothData (ID_frame integer not null, RSSI varchar(255), MAC varchar(255), TimeStamp timestamp, Vendor TEXT, ID TEXT, cod varchar(255), primary key (ID_frame))
2016-05-05 15:44:31.020(GMT)[main] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Wrong data type: TEXT in statement [create table bluetoothData (ID_frame integer not null, RSSI varchar(255), MAC varchar(255), TimeStamp timestamp, Vendor TEXT]
```

If I remove the `columnDefinition` property from `vendor` the problem goes away and my tests can run, however as I described above the application won't start.  So I'm stuck in a situation where I can change the code to make the application work but the tests fail, or the tests fail and the application works.

One solution that I've seen mentioned elsewhere was to change the `@Column` annotation to use the `length` property and remove `columnDefintion` so that I have:

```
@Column(name = "Vendor", length=255)
private String vendor;
```

This change allows my tests pass but still throws the original exception on start up.

Is there a solution that will allow both my tests and my application to function properly while using MySql in production and hsqldb in my unit tests?

Comment: Could you add a property in your resources folder so that either text or VARCHAR is set dynamically depending on whether its a test?

Comment: Any idea what such a property would look like? The fact that it's a Spring Boot app, a framework I'm not particularly familiar with, makes it more difficult to see for myself.

Comment: Thinking about it since the bean won't be created by Spring you won't be able to do it that way - sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a little research reveals that you can set H2 to act in MYSQL mode.

I believe if you change your database URL to have `MODE=MySQL`at the end it should work!

Edit: If you wish to stick with HSQL, they also have an equivalent property -  sql.syntax_mys=true

Comment: This worked. I changed my datasource url from: `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:meshlium` to `jdbc:h2:~/meshlium;MODE=MySQL`.  A quick note for anyone else reading this later is that this involved switching from an hsqldb dabatase to an h2 databse, which wasn't an issue in my case.

Comment: I think in fact you could have avoided switching to H2 by appending sql.syntax_mys=true instead.  My apologies I misread HSQL as H2...

Comment: Switched back to hsqldb and that property has done the trick.